# Using Javascript to edit the content of an html input element

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input tag with no initial value, along with three text elements:

```
<input type='text' value=''/>
<p id='1'>Alpha</p>
<p id='2'>Beta</p>
<p id='3'>Gamma</p>
```

What I want to do, through JavaScript, is to add 'alpha' to the input value when the user clicks on the text that says 'Alpha'. Then, if the user proceeds to click on beta, I want 'Beta' to be added to the value. So if the user clicks alpha then beta, I want the input value to be 'alpha beta'. I need this to work for any combination of the three words clicked.

In other words, I'm looking for javascript to take a certain value and add it on to the end of the input value, not replace it altogether.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest you to use jQuery. in html, update class and id:

```
<input type='text' value='' id='inputTarget'/>
<p id='1' class='textInput'>Alpha</p>
<p id='2' class='textInput'>Beta</p>
<p id='3' class='textInput'>Gamma</p>
```

in js:

```
$('.textInput').onclick(function(){
   var t = $('#inputTarget').val();
   t += ' ' + $(this).text();
   $('#inputTarget').val(t);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A vanilla JavaScript alternative (I have added the an id attribute to the input):

```
var inputTarget = document.getElementById("inputTarget");

var els = document.querySelectorAll("p");
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  els[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    inputTarget.value = inputTarget.value + " " + e.target.innerHTML;
  });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tfsrrny4/